# Smooth rotation issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have searched all over for a solution to my problem on smooth rotation.  I can get it 99% working however there is one small issue that keeps messing with me.  The rotations works fine except when the target makes a drastic change.  The basic idea is I have a ball and a player when the player comes in contact with the ball he changes the balls direction and speed.  The player follows the ball correctly however when he comes in contact with the ball or the ball's location is reset thus making the delta between the angles greater than 45 degrees the player instantly jumps to fact the ball.  Here is the code that I have partly working.  Thank you for any help in advance.

```
var newFacing = Math.atan2(theBall.y-player.y,theBall.x-player.x);
var diff = (Math.abs(newFacing) - Math.abs(player.facing));
if (diff < Math.PI*0.1 && diff > -Math.PI*0.1){
    player.facing = newFacing;
}else if (diff > Math.PI) {
    player.facing -= Math.PI*0.1;
} else {
    player.facing += Math.PI*0.1;
} 
if (player.facing > Math.PI) {
    player.facing -= Math.PI*2;
} else if (player.facing < -Math.PI) {
    player.facing += Math.PI*2;
}
```

Updated: Changed the || to && and added a condition to ensure I do not go above or below PI radians.  There are still some odd rotational issues at some angles.  For example if the ball passes below the player he will rotate clockwise to follow rather than the logical counter clockwise.  At times the player will do a full 360 before tracking the ball again.  Without tracing it I am not sure what conditions are causing this.

Comment: Can you give is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pKdDc/  Never done this before so I think this is correct.

Comment: This has nothing to do with smooth, but this condition: (diff < Math.PI*0.1 || diff > -Math.PI*0.1) is always true ...

Comment: @JimDziak, you can edit your post and add the fiddle link to the bottom ...

Comment: @ToniAlmeida How is that always true if the angle is great than about 0.3 or less than about -0.3 it will be false.  If I reverse this I get a jumping where even at small changes it it will adjust by 0.3 radians

Comment: But that's an OR condition, that statement (resumed) is like saying that some number, is smaller than 1 [-oo ; 1] **OR** greater than -1 [-1 ; +oo]. The OR condition turns this always true ... [-oo ; +oo]

Comment: You probably wanted to use the &&. **AND** turns your range into this: [-pi/10; +pi/10] // [-0.314; +0.314]

Comment: I think I am still missing something.  0.5 is less than 1 yet greater than -1 so there is a condition where that OR statement is not true.  Unless my understanding of OR is off.

Comment: Ok yes I see it now because OR is exclusive not inclusive.  The && fixed the basic problem how every sometimes I will get stuck in a loop where the player spins in place because I have going over 2*PI